# How to change JAVA SWING control name in Netbean's design mode

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I am using Netbeans 8.0.2 IDE for a java swing application development. When I add a control to a jframe it gets a name with a default initialization manner. But I want to change the name of the control.

In the property list there is something called name, I changed it, But It was not successful. Again when i add an action, it takes the previous name. In coding section I can see this generated name but it is not able to modify. I want to know. How I should change the control name property using Netbeans.

```
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
```

Ex:- I want to change this jButton1 in to a custom name (say btnOk) using Netbeans design mode.

Comment: Its variable name. I want to change "jButton1" in to "cmdOk"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try doing this

> right click on the button >- change variable name >- your custom name

Comment: I wonder why this is not part of the properties container ... I get that the name of the variable actually is NOT a property of the control, however that's where I looked for it nevertheless. Having to right-click something to change is not my number one intuive way of trying.